# XSD for auto closing tag in complexType

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd

I have this in my XML file:

```
<rooms>
   <room id="1" beds="1" windows="0"/>
   <room id="2" beds="2" windows="0"/>
 </rooms>
```

And this in my XSD file:

```
<xs:complexType name="Rooms">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="room" type="Room"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="count" type="xs:integer"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Room">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:attribute name="beds" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:attribute name="windows" type="xs:integer"/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

But I got this error : Element 'room': This element is not expected.
When I put `<room id="1" beds="1" windows="0"></room>` I don't have the error anymore and if I have only one room I don't have the error, so it's basically because of the auto closing tag.
How can I fix this?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the tag being self-closing, It's because you have more than one `<room>` element and the schema only allows one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying values for **minOccurs** and **maxOccurs** to your room element inside the sequence. I think the default expected number of occurrences is 1. Something like:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="room" type="Room" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
</xs:sequence>
```